# Убрать повторяющие элементы в объекте

Tags: javascript

Нужно убрать с объекта повторяющие имена и вывести его
Должно выводить объект без 1 Beyonce а не выводит ничего
Если добавить массив то работает а с объектом не хочет

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [   
  {
      name: 'Diana',
      born: 130000, // Mon, Jul 15 2013
      num: 4,
      sex: 'female'
  },
  {

      name: 'Beyonce',
      born: 1363000, // Wed, Apr 24 2013
      num: 2,
      sex: 'female'
  },
  {

    name: 'Beyonce',
    born: 1363000, // Wed, Apr 24 2013
    num: 2,
    sex: 'female'
},
  {            
      name: 'Albert',
      born: 13000, // Mon, Jun 3 2013
      num: 3,
      sex: 'male'
  },    
  {
      name: 'Doris',
      born: 187000, // Sat, Dec 1 2012
      num: 1,
      sex: 'female'
  }
];


var names = arrayOfObjects.slice(0);
var eeee= names.filter(function(item, pos) {
  
    return   names.indexOf(item.name) == pos;
    
})
console.log(eeee);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) сравнивает переданный параметр со всем элементом, так как ты передаешь строку, а элементы это массивы, то ничего не находится, возвращается `-1` и так как `pos` не может быть `-1` всегда возвращается `false`.

для решения достаточно заменить `indexOf`, на [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), который принимает функцию.

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [{
    name: 'Diana',
    born: 130000, // Mon, Jul 15 2013
    num: 4,
    sex: 'female'
  },
  {

    name: 'Beyonce',
    born: 1363000, // Wed, Apr 24 2013
    num: 2,
    sex: 'female'
  },
  {

    name: 'Beyonce',
    born: 1363000, // Wed, Apr 24 2013
    num: 2,
    sex: 'female'
  },
  {
    name: 'Albert',
    born: 13000, // Mon, Jun 3 2013
    num: 3,
    sex: 'male'
  },
  {
    name: 'Doris',
    born: 187000, // Sat, Dec 1 2012
    num: 1,
    sex: 'female'
  }
];


var names = arrayOfObjects.slice(0);
var eeee = names.filter(function(item, pos) {

  return names.findIndex(el => el.name == item.name) == pos;

})
console.log(eeee);
```

---

Альтернативным решением может стать проверка наличия конкретного имени, в каком-то на наборе и при его отсутствии добавление и сохранение элемента в результат.

Например:

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [{
    name: 'Diana',
    born: 130000, // Mon, Jul 15 2013
    num: 4,
    sex: 'female'
  },
  {

    name: 'Beyonce',
    born: 1363000, // Wed, Apr 24 2013
    num: 2,
    sex: 'female'
  },
  {

    name: 'Beyonce',
    born: 1363000, // Wed, Apr 24 2013
    num: 2,
    sex: 'female'
  },
  {
    name: 'Albert',
    born: 13000, // Mon, Jun 3 2013
    num: 3,
    sex: 'male'
  },
  {
    name: 'Doris',
    born: 187000, // Sat, Dec 1 2012
    num: 1,
    sex: 'female'
  }
];


var eeee = arrayOfObjects.reduce(function({
  map,
  res
}, el) {

  if (!map[el.name]) { // если элемента с таким именем не было добавляем в результат
    map[el.name] = true; // помечаем что такой элемент был
    res.push(el);
  }
  return {
    map,
    res
  };

}, {
  map: {},
  res: []
}).res;
console.log(eeee);
```

Comment: спасибо большое